# Associative table hibernate mapping

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm getting a mapping error and I'd like some help to find the problem.

I have two tables (**TBLAUCTIONHEADER** and **TBLUSER**). I added a third table to associate users to auctionheaders (**TBLAUCTIONHEADERUSER**). This third table has only two columns (userid and auctionheaderid), which are foreign keys of the ids of the tblauctionheader and tbluser tables.

I mapped it in the hbm file of auctionheader, this way:

```
<bag name="eventApprovers" table="TBLAUCTIONHEADERUSER" fetch="select" lazy="true">
        <key column="AUCTIONHEADERID"/>
        <many-to-many column="USERID" class="com.lalala.user.dataobject.User"/>
</bag>
```

and I created a list in the AuctionHeader.java class:

```
//many-to-many

private List<User> eventApprovers;
```

in my action, when I call `aucHeader.getEventApprovers();`, I get the following errors in my log:

```
Exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [com.lalala.auction.admin.dataobject.AuctionHeader.eventApprovers#12000]
```

and

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "EVENTAPPRO0_"."AUCTIONHEADERID": invalid identifier
```

I didn't understand why/how the identifier "EVENTAPPRO0_"."AUCTIONHEADERID" is created.

Does anyone have any idea what am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem myself.

I was mapping the wrong column name:

where I had set:

```
<bag name="eventApprovers" table="TBLAUCTIONHEADERUSER" fetch="select" lazy="true">
    <key column="AUCTIONHEADERID"/>
    <many-to-many column="USERID" class="com.lalala.user.dataobject.User"/>
</bag>
```

The `key column` should be just `HEADERID`, so:

```
<bag name="eventApprovers" table="TBLAUCTIONHEADERUSER" fetch="select" lazy="true">
        <key column="HEADERID"/>
        <many-to-many column="USERID" class="com.lalala.user.dataobject.User"/>
</bag>
```

And this was the problem.